# What's the best tutorial for learning Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm new to Mongo DB and Mongoid (and still kinda new to Ruby on Rails). Since Ryan Bates dosen't happen to have a Mongoid Railscast, I need pointers to other good tutorials/screencasts.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you are looking for [MongoDB & Mongoid - RubyJax February 2010](http://vimeo.com/9864311) It's the introduction to Mongoid by his creator!

Answer (score 16):

There is now a Railscast for Mongoid: http://railscasts.com/episodes/238-mongoid

Answer (score 7):

I find it best to read over the [documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html), scan the [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid), then just start looking at code.

Here are a couple apps that use mongoid:

- http://github.com/fortuity/rails3-mongoid-devise
- http://github.com/fortuity/rails3-subdomain-devise

Good luck.

Comment: the rails3-mongoid-decvise tuts are excellent!

Answer (score 1):

great one [here](http://socialmemorycomplex.net/2010/06/02/gridfs-with-mongoid-and-carrierwave-on-rails-3/) about using gridFS, mongoid and carrier-wave

Answer (score 0):

Just start using it.
It's pretty easy and if it's missing something that you think should be there, just add it as a support ticket on the github issue tracker. Don't forget to include why you think it should be there. (http://github.com/durran/mongoid/issues)